# cummulative count when there is no rows but if all those rows are assigned to someone else then show zero instead of cummulative count

Tags: mysql

Earlier I have following query which provides me count for any given day for the ProductionFacility='Unassigned' and also excludes the rows If any of those UniqueFormIds are assigned to some other ProductionFacility

```
SELECT 'Unassigned',0,'2023-12-04',
        COUNT(DISTINCT UniqueFormId )   ,    
        COUNT(DISTINCT UniqueFormId )       
        FROM detail
        WHERE ProductionFacility='Unassigned'and DATE(StatusDateTime)<='2023-12-04'
        and UniqueFormId not in ( select DISTINCT UniqueFormId from detail as exd where DATE(exd.StatusDateTime) <= '2023-12-04' and
        exd.ProductionStatusNo!=1 )
```

to improve the performance I changes the not in (exclude logic) into left join with null check and also as I have to run the query from 1st to 31st . so I left join with the date_range table, as follow :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Dashboard_Unassigned_Insert`(
IN p_StartDate DATE,
IN p_UnassignedProductionFaciltiy nvarchar(500)
)
BEGIN
        truncate table unassigned ; 
        DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS date_range;
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE date_range AS
        SELECT DATE(p_StartDate) + INTERVAL (n-1) DAY AS StatusDate
        FROM (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n
          FROM detail 
          LIMIT 31 
        ) AS StatusDate;
        
        
        INSERT INTO unassigned(ProductionStatus,ProductionStatusNo,StatusDate,DayCount,CumulativeCount)
         
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(result.ProductionStatus, 'Unassigned') AS ProductionStatus,
            COALESCE(result.ProductionStatusNo, 0) AS ProductionStatusNo,
            dr.StatusDate, 
            COALESCE(result.DayCount, 0) AS DayCount,
            COALESCE(result.CumulativeCount, 0) AS CumulativeCount
        FROM date_range  as dr
        LEFT JOIN  (
                SELECT 
                    'Unassigned' AS ProductionStatus,  
                    0 AS ProductionStatusNo,   
                    d.StatusDate, 
                    COUNT(DISTINCT d.UniqueFormId) as DayCount, 
                    SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT d.UniqueFormId)) OVER (ORDER BY d.StatusDate) as CumulativeCount 
                FROM 
                    detail d 
                LEFT JOIN ( 
                    SELECT DISTINCT UniqueFormId, StatusDate
                    FROM detail exd 
                    WHERE exd.ProductionStatusNo != 1 
                ) exd ON d.UniqueFormId = exd.UniqueFormId AND exd.StatusDate <= d.StatusDate
                WHERE 
                    d.ProductionFacility = 'KY_KIT' 
                    AND exd.UniqueFormId IS NULL 
                GROUP BY 
                    d.StatusDate
                ORDER BY 
                    d.StatusDate) as result  ON dr.StatusDate=result.StatusDate ;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But Now I am facing issue that when there is no row in detail table lets say on 5th there is no rows for unassigned then its shows zero , but it should be same count as I have on 4th , second thing on 6th those  all are assigned to some other productionfacility then it should be zero as there are no more unassigned records.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering issues with the logic when there are no rows for the 'Unassigned' ProductionFacility or when all the records are assigned to some other ProductionFacility. The challenge is to generate a continuous series of dates and ensure that the counts align correctly for 'Unassigned' records, even when they are absent in the 'detail' table for specific dates.

To handle these scenarios, you'll need to modify the SQL logic to generate a continuous date range and correctly calculate the counts for 'Unassigned' ProductionFacility. Here's an adjusted version of your SQL procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Dashboard_Unassigned_Insert`(
IN p_StartDate DATE,
IN p_UnassignedProductionFaciltiy NVARCHAR(500)
)
BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE unassigned;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS date_range;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE date_range AS
    SELECT DATE(p_StartDate) + INTERVAL (n-1) DAY AS StatusDate
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n
        FROM detail 
        LIMIT 31 
    ) AS StatusDate;

    INSERT INTO unassigned(ProductionStatus, ProductionStatusNo, StatusDate, DayCount, CumulativeCount)
    SELECT 
        'Unassigned' AS ProductionStatus,
        0 AS ProductionStatusNo,
        dr.StatusDate, 
        COALESCE(result.DayCount, 0) AS DayCount,
        COALESCE(SUM(result.DayCount) OVER (ORDER BY dr.StatusDate), 0) AS CumulativeCount
    FROM date_range AS dr
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            DATE(d.StatusDateTime) AS StatusDate, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN exd.UniqueFormId IS NULL THEN d.UniqueFormId END) AS DayCount
        FROM detail d
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT UniqueFormId
            FROM detail exd 
            WHERE exd.ProductionStatusNo != 1 
        ) exd ON d.UniqueFormId = exd.UniqueFormId AND DATE(exd.StatusDateTime) <= DATE(d.StatusDateTime)
        WHERE d.ProductionFacility = p_UnassignedProductionFaciltiy 
        GROUP BY DATE(d.StatusDateTime)
    ) AS result ON dr.StatusDate = result.StatusDate;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This adjusted SQL procedure uses a LEFT JOIN between the generated date range and the aggregated counts of 'Unassigned' records per day. It ensures that even if there are no records for a specific day in the 'detail' table for the 'Unassigned' ProductionFacility, it will still display a count of zero for that day. Also, it calculates cumulative counts for 'Unassigned' ProductionStatus across the given date range. Adjust the 'p_UnassignedProductionFaciltiy' parameter according to your needs.

Make sure to test this adjusted logic with different scenarios to ensure it covers all cases accurately.